# Python: Implementation of a threshold model using odeint

Tags: python, differential-equations, threshold, numerical-integration

The problem I'm dealing with (the shown example is highly simplified) seems like a common problem but I haven't found a solution yet. I have three different reactions, v1, v2 and v3, that are defined as follows:

v1: R <-> A + C; v1 = k1*(R - A*C/5000.)

v2: R <-> B + C; v2 = k2*(R - B*C/5000.)

v3: A + B -> P; v3 = k3*A*B

Using a resource R, the first two reactions produce A and C and B and C, respectively, whereas the third reaction converts A and B to a product P (k1, k2, k3 are constants, here they are set to 1).

The third reaction is supposed to occur only if C exceeds a certain threshold called Cthr (here: Cthr = 25), otherwise v3 is 0. So the idea is that C accumulates which then, once a certain concentration is reached, results in the production of the product P.

I implemented that as follows:

```
def thresholdmodel (yn,tvec,allpara,R):

    (A, B, C, P) = yn

    k1, k2, k3 = allpara['kv']    

    Cthr = allpara['Cthresh']

    if C <= Cthr:
        v3 = 0
    else:      
        v3 = k3*A*B
        C = 0 #does not(!) affect the ouput, why?

    v1 = k1*(R - A*C/5000.)
    v2 = k2*(R - B*C/5000.)

    dA = v1 - v3
    dB = v2 - v3
    dC = v1 + v2
    dP = v3

    return (dA, dB, dC, dP)
```

The simulation's output looks like this: http://i50.tinypic.com/apdvkj.png

So apparently it works until the threshold is reached for the first time (v3 is 0, P is not produced) but afterwards C is not set to 0 and I have no idea why.
What I want to get is: C is produced until the threshold, drops to 0, is produced again, drops to 0 and so on, looking like a sawtooth wave.
The time course of P should look like stairs (only produced when Cthr is exceeded).

Does anyone know what I have to do in order to set C back to 0 and to receive the expected output? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand you equations, but I can tell why `C` doesn't drops to 0.

Because `C` is a local variable in `thresholdmodel()`, changes `C` to any value will not change the status in `odeint`. `odeint` will always integrate `dC` returned by `thresholdmodel()`. So `C` will increase continuously.

Edit:

C will increase continuously, so you need to change the threshold every time C > threshold, such as:

```
lastC = 0

def thresholdmodel (yn,tvec,allpara,R):
    global lastC
    (A, B, C, P) = yn

    k1, k2, k3 = allpara['kv']    

    Cthr = allpara['Cthresh']

    if C <= lastC + Cthr:
        v3 = 0
    else:      
        v3 = k3*A*B
        lastC = C

    v1 = k1*(R - A*C/5000.)
    v2 = k2*(R - B*C/5000.)

    dA = v1 - v3
    dB = v2 - v3
    dC = v1 + v2
    dP = v3

    return (dA, dB, dC, dP)
```

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for your quick response!

Well, that is only a toy example to illustrate the problem I have. What exactly do you don't understand? There are only simple mass action kinetics applied, nothing special.

So, thanks for clarifying the problem! Do you know a feasible way to fix it?

Comment: I don't know what <-> and -> means. And If C can drop to 0 by C=0 in your code, then v3 will almost be 0, and only be k3*A*B when C == 0. Is this your intention？

Comment: Thanks again for your reply! '<->' means that the reaction is reversible (bidirectional), '->' that it is irreversible (only one direction).
Well, almost: v3 is zero for all Cs that are smaller than the threshold (Cthr). Once that threshold is reached, v3 becomes k3*A*B and P can be produced. Afterwards C is set to zero again, v3 therefore becomes zero, C is built up again until the threshold is reached the next time and so on. But since C is only a local variable, it seems to be difficult to set it to zero in the overall output, as you pointed out. Any suggestions to solve this?

Comment: I added an possible solution to the answer, please check it.

Comment: Thanks, didn't see that. 
I checked it: When I print v3, it is always zero except for the time point when C exceeds the threshold: so far so good. But P remains 0, it does not increase, although dP is greater than 0 (equals to v3).
The problem seemed rather simple but apparently it is not. Maybe I have to use a Runge-Kutta-integrator implemented by hand. Then it should be easy to manipulate C in the intended way but I would still prefer to use the built-in function. Anyway, thanks a lot for your comments and suggestions!